# Responsive 2 Column Divs Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We've tried every Responsive 2 Column Divs we could find, but they're not working.  I've included some links below to ones we have tried.  Any idea why they're not working?  We just want to divs that will stack when the screen is made smaller. Thanks in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/fkp8d/1/

```
<div class="group">
<div class="left">
    <p>tates enim officiis. Iste repudiandae illo nulla sed nam a ratione iure?</p>
</div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/" alt="" />
  </div>
 </div>

<style>
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.group:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .left, .right {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }
  } </style>
```

Also:
http://jsfiddle.net/8YLXy/

Comment: your first fiddle works, what is the issue? although it can be simplied

Comment: Yes brother your first fiddle is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first fiddle works fine, your second needed an adjustment, to this

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8YLXy/19/)

Here I floated the sidebar, instead of absolute positioning, and switched the children in the markup (the `float: right` need to be first)

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 250px;
}
.main-area {
  background: red;
  margin-right: 250px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .sidebar {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
  .main-area {
    margin-right: 0;
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    <div class="main-area">main content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This still didn't work for me, both of them.  Any ideas why?  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @H.I: How does it not work? Did you test the above snippet or fiddle or run your own updated code? Which browser do you use?

Comment: It works in the browser, but not when I add it to my site, which is just a blank html page.  I didn't add any CSS or JS.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: @H.I Which means it does work though you don't know how to implement it into your own site/page?

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.group:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .left, .right {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div class="group">
            <div class="left">
                <p>tates enim officiis. Iste repudiandae illo nulla sed nam a ratione iure?</p>
            </div>
              <div class="right">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/" alt="" />
              </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  This still doesn't work for me.  Any ideas why?

Comment: when click on run code snippet and resize browser works or not?

Comment: It works in the browser, but not when I add it to my site, which is just a blank html page.  I didn't add any CSS or JS.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: @eshan  I found that it works in Firefox, but not in Safari